# Extract values from block of data

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have the below block of data.

```
Heap after GC invocations=31 (full 3):  
 par new generation   total 131008K, used 0K [0x00000000eac00000, 0x00000000f2c00000, 0x00000000f2c00000)  
  eden space 130944K,   0% used [0x00000000eac00000, 0x00000000eac00000,   0x00000000f2be0000)
  from space 64K,   0% used [0x00000000f2be0000, 0x00000000f2be0000, 0x00000000f2bf0000)  
  to   space 64K,   0% used [0x00000000f2bf0000, 0x00000000f2bf0000, 0x00000000f2c00000)  
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 131072K, used 48549K [0x00000000f2c00000, 0x00000000fac00000, 0x00000000fac00000)  
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 30000K, used 19518K [0x00000000fac00000, 0x00000000fc94c000, 0x0000000100000000)  
}
```

I need to extract the below data of "total" and "used" numeric data without "K" for the below. i.e. `value1=131008, value2=0,value3=131072,value4=48549,value5=30000 and value6=19518`

should be extracted from the below:

```
par new generation   ***total*** 131008K, ***used*** 0K
concurrent mark-sweep generation ***total*** 131072K, used 48549K 
concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen ***total*** 30000K, ***used*** 19518K
```

I know how to extract the data for fixed length values like below.

```
value1=`grep "par new generation" | cut -c27-31
```

However, the above block of data has variable length values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to extract those six numbers into shell variables, it is probably more convenient to put them in a bash array like this:

```
$ data=($(awk '/^ *(par|concurrent)/{printf "%s %s ",$5+0,$7+0}' file))
```

You can verify that the array has the correct values using `declare`:

```
$ declare -p data
declare -a data='([0]="131008" [1]="0" [2]="131072" [3]="48549" [4]="30000" [5]="19518")'
```

If, instead, you just want to print the values:

```
$ awk '/^ *(par|concurrent)/{printf "value%s=%s\nvalue%s=%s\n",++c,$5+0,++c,$7+0}' file
value1=131008
value2=0
value3=131072
value4=48549
value5=30000
value6=19518
```

#### How is works

- `/^ *(par|concurrent)/`

  This matches only on the lines that start with `par` or `concurrent`.
- `printf "%s %s ",$5+0,$7+0`

  For the matched lines, we print out the fifth and seventh fields.  By adding zero to these values, we force awk to convert them to numbers.  This has the side-effect of removing the `k`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not expect such quick resolution.